# Abrir PDF no iOS mobile utilizando Xamarin - C#

Tags: c#, ios, mobile, pdf, xamarin

Alguém sabe como faço para abrir um PDF que está na pasta local do iOS utilizando a plataforma Xamarin?
Já pesquisei e testei de várias formas, mas nenhuma funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito prático de abrir um .pdf é utilizando uma `UIWebView`:

```
var url = new NSUrl(caminhoPdf);
var request = new NSUrlRequest(url);

webView.LoadRequest(request);
```